# Is there a way to read a file into memory using DMA in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory, dma

Say, I have a huge file which I want to load into memory. Is it possible to use the DMA to quickly load the data from the file into the memory in Linux? If so, how?

Comment: What makes you think that *all* file reads aren't done via DMA? Do you mean you want to access HW directly rather than calling `mmap` or something along those lines?

Comment: Does fread also uses DMA for copying large data?

Comment: Hard drive controllers, such as the built in SATA interface on a motherboard use a bus mastering controller which supports scatter / gather in order to work with virtual paged memory. The virtual memory is "locked", and the physical pages and lengths are programmed into an array of "descriptors". For large I/O with a single command, the "descriptors" may get reprogrammed during the I/O.

Comment: Your code interacts with the kernel using [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Use `strace` to find out which. So your question about `fread` using `DMA` does not have much sense: `fread` uses `read(2)` which is done by the kernel which might do DMA (*inside* the kernel).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8174338/841108) question, which is *almost* a duplicate (but phrased differently)

Answer (score 4):

If DMA is available then the driver is probably already using it. If you want high-speed direct access to a file then use `mmap(2)` instead of second-guessing the OS.